# ReactJS only show header if not on home page

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to hide the `<Header/>` only on the home page. But I need it to show on the other pages - for example when the user is logged in.

I thought it was possible to have to `Routes` that both had home in it but did different things.

I see it is possible to do this:

```
  <Router>  
        <Switch>  
          <Route exact path="/">  
            <Redirect to="/layout1" />  
          </Route>  
          <LoginLayoutRoute path="/layout1" component={LoginPage} />  
          <DashboardRoute path="/layout2" component={UserPage} />  
        </Switch>


  </Router>
```

However all I want to do is not show  if on `/`

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import './App.css';

/* PAGES */
import Header from './core/Header'; 
import Home from './core/pages/Home'; 
//import DashboardWrapper from './core/wrappers/DashboardWrapper';
/* END PAGES */


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary1Color: "#fff",
    primary2Color: "#c62828",
    accent1Color: "#ffffff",
    pickerHeaderColor: "#fce4ec",
  },
});

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Use props.match.url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Here you are including Header under `ThemeProvider` directly and not under `Switch` and therefore it is being displayed on all paths!
Move Header component under the Route component you want it to render into!

```
<Route exact to='/path'>
 <Header/>
 <YourComponent />
<Route />
```

Comment: hmm but if there are many components apart from `Home`, this means code duplication.

Comment: you can then try path matching to cause conditional rendering!

Answer (score 1):

You can move `<Header />` inside each route that would need it

```
     <Router>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
          <Route exact path="/otherRoute">
            <Header />
            <OtherComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/layout">
            <Header />
            <Layout/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check the value of `location.pathname` and render - or not - the header.

Check my sandbox.

`App` component is checking the `react-router-dom` specific parameters and if the `location.pathname` parameter is equal to "/", it hides the tag.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ritchie-4gq2u

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by allow your `App` component to have access to routes parameter like this

Perform some change in the `index.js`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

And in the `App` component you can use the `withRouter` hook to have access to the path which is beeing visited.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function App({match, location, history}) {
    const homePathPattern = /^\/$/;
    const isHome = homePathPattern.test(location.pathname)
    
    return (<>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>

        {isHome && <Header/> }

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        </Switch>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </>);
}

export default withRouter(App);
```